# Is server-side rendering always efficient?

Tags: angular, reactjs, server-side-rendering

I had this question in my mind for a while.

So let's assume that we have a front-end server that has enough load and hit for **just** for sending files over the network to client.

Would you still say server-side rendering would make it more performant? or it will actually decrease it in this scenario (I ask this because actually maybe server has to do more processing which I believe has)

IMO the initial thoughts and idea of server-side rendering is your Front-End server is able to process the file and send it back faster than client computer? otherwise it's pointless???

I don't have strong opinion on this and that's why I asked it here :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this as *primarily opinion based*. There is no blanket right and wrong answer here that can be provided. Do more research and come to your own conclusion on where and when to use SSR compared to SPA's and which is applicable to your implementation.

Comment: @Zze if you can't give direction and guide that doesn't mean it is a general opinionated question....  as I mentioned I don't have strong opinion and want to see others experience in industry or world...

Comment: is this title sounds opinionated to you ??  `Is server-side rendering always efficient?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long story short sentence nothing is **always** efficient. Specially in computing world.

But as @Abhishek Mehandiratta mentioned the spirit of the Server-Side Rendering(SSR) is to decrease the initial render time. While decreasing the initial load has a huge impact in term of user experience its still has it's own trade off.

I would say the benefit that a company gets from efficiency and user experience of the initial render is far superior to the impact that is to the server load.

There is still a space for debate, it still depends on the requirements and the use case. Considering Facebook user-interface with [`30 000` react component](https://code.fb.com/web/react-16-a-look-inside-an-api-compatible-rewrite-of-our-frontend-ui-library/) (including mobile and web) might be different to compare with a website that has only 100 component...

When it comes to scalability and availability of services and servers it gets quite tricky. In order to handle such a load and render time there is quite a bit of techniques that they are using.

- [Lazy load components (code splitting)](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html)
- [Concurrent rendering (it's more of a time slicing approach)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ByBPyMBTzM0&t=704s)
- Caching
- .... (and many more)

Previously apart from inital render time, server-side rendering had a **HUGE** benefit of Search Engine Optimisation(SEO) because web crawler couldn't crawl javascript generated pages. But most of the modern search engines are now crawling and capable of parsing javascript generated pages([read this if this topic interests you](https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/crawl-javascript-seo/%20if%20this%20interests%20you))

Also you will be able to learn from [Walmart experience](https://medium.com/walmartlabs/the-benefits-of-server-side-rendering-over-client-side-rendering-5d07ff2cefe8) of migrating to a server-side rendering for their react front-end web.

Answer (score 1):

SSR makes your app performant by significantly decreasing the initial render time, but of course it comes at a price of increased load on the server. It depends on your app and the capability of the server whether you want to go for SSR or not. In case of react, renderToString method is sync. If you want to make this process async, react 16+ gives a method [renderToNodeStream](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertonodestream). I don't know about angular though.